Question about one-point compactification
Let $T = (S,\tau)$ be a non-empty topological space. 
Let $p$ be a new element not in $S$. 
Let $S^∗:=S\cup\{p\}$. 
Let $T^∗=(S^∗,\tau^∗)$ be the Alexandroff extension on $S$. 
I want to show that $T^*$ is compact.
I found this proof that says:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $T^*$.
At least one $V \in \mathcal{U}$ contains $p$.
Because $p \notin S$, $V$ is not an open set of $T$.
Therefore, by definition of the Alexandroff extension, $V$ must be the
complement relative to $S^*$ of a closed set, $C_{S^*} V$ of $T$.
Because $C_{S^*} V$ is compact topological subspace, it can be
covered by a finite number of sets in $\mathcal{U}$.
So $T^*$ can be covered by $V$ and that finite number of sets in
$\mathcal{U}$ are a cover for $C_{S^*} V$.
That is, $\mathcal{U}$ has a finite subcover.

But... my question is.. from where I know that there certainly exists an open set from $T$ in that cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $T^*$? If all sets from that open cover contains the element $p$? Then I can't find a subcover of $C_{S^*}(V)$ in $T$.

You're right that the proof skips that point. To show that $\mathcal{U}$ has a finite subcover of $\complement_{S^*}(V)$, you need to know that $\complement_{S^*}(V)$ is compact as a subspace of $T^*$. That way, any open-in-$T^*$ cover of $\complement_{S^*}(V)$ has a finite subcover.
Note that $T$ has the subspace topology from $T^*$:
\begin{align*}
    \{U \cap S : U \in \tau^*\}
    &=\{U \cap S : U \in \tau\} \cup \{U \cap ((S \setminus K) \cup \{p\}) :\text{$K$ closed and compact in $T$}\}
    \\&= \{U : U \in \tau\} \cup \{S \setminus K : \text{$K$ closed and compact in $T$}\}
    \\&= \tau \qquad\text{(since each $S \setminus K \in \tau$)}.
\end{align*}
By assumption, $\complement_{S^*}(V)$ is compact in the subspace topology induced from $T$, which has the subspace topology from $T^*$. It follows that $\complement_{S^*}(V)$ is compact in the subspace topology from $T^*$.
So the open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of the compact subset $\complement_{S^*}(V)$ of $T^*$ has a finite subcover.
